# SQL Server CLR Aggregate: Serialize a Dictionary?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlclr

I'm writing a custom CLR Aggregate in C# to run in SQL Server 2008. I want to hold most of my `SqlUserDefinedAggregate` instances' states in Dictionaries, so I can't use the builtin serialization.

How can I go about using `UserDefined` serialization with the `Read()` and `Write()` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using keys and values of types that `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` handle, Write each Dictionary out to the BinaryWriter in key0,value0...keyN-1,valueN-1 order. Prefix this sequence with Dictionary's `Count`. After the sequence, write a constant to verify end of dictionary. Personally I like `0xDEADBEEF`.

For deserialization, do the reverse: Intialize a loop to run n times (n is the first integer in your stream), and add to Dictionary as you read in key/value pairs. At the end, check for your constant.